# SQL regular expression to get number

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I have these time fields in my db:

```
0400 - 0530
0430 - 0530
0930 - 1050
1000 - 1130
1400 - 1450
```

Users can input 2 characters for a start time. `04` would then return:

```
0400 - 0530
0430 - 0530
```

I currently use a check to get the start time: `to_char(a.time, 'hh24')`

I want to be able to modify this so I am actually getting times in that range. For example, `10` would return:

```
1000 - 1130
```

I need it to return:

```
0930 - 1050
1000 - 1050
```

My thought is to use a regular expression to get the 2 digits after `-`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle. Not sure why someone removed the tags.

Comment: Are these times actually stored as `DATE` values, or as the strings you have represented above?

Comment: Strings. (char11) It's a custom field based on two time fields `start` and `end` that have values like `3:30:00.000000PM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to check to see if the input digits, which look like they represent the hour-portion of the time, match either the start or end hours, you can try:

```
select * from table where
regexp_substr(time_string, '^\d\d') = input_string
or regexp_replace(regexp_substr(time_string, '-\s*\d\d'), '-\s*', '') = input_string
```

Or if you would like to try matching the actual `DATE` columns, you can try something like:

```
select * from table where
to_char(start, 'HH24') = input_string
or to_char(end, 'HH24') = input_string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
^(\d{4} - 10\d{2}|10\d{2} - \d{4})$
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/nQ8hL5/1)

Use `[0-9]` in place of `\d` if not supported.

Sample query

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column_name, '^(\d{4} - 10\d{2}|10\d{2} - \d{4})$')
```

---

Have a look at

- [Oracle REGEXP_LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm)
- [Using Regular Expressions in Oracle Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm)